# NestGraph Basics

Tags: graphs-and-networks

**Summary**

How does NestGraph build a graph?

**Example**

```
Column[NestList[{2 #, 2 # + 1} &, 0, 2]]
0
{0, 1}
{{0, 2}, {1, 3}}
```

Now NestGraph[{2 #, 2 # + 1} &, 0, 2, VertexLabels -> All] produces this graph:

[image]

The first NestList row, 0, makes sense - draw a graph from 0 to itself (hence the zero loop in the image). The second row seems to imply that we should go from vertex 0 to vertex 1, hence that directed edge. What I can't figure out is what the third row {{0, 2}, {1, 3}} is indicating to NestGraph - how does that determine the shown directed edges? Sorry for the newbie question but there you go. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the documentation, especially the second one?

Comment: That's actually very helpful; I discovered that:

NestGraph[Mod[#^2 + 1, 10] &, Range[0, 9], VertexLabels -> Automatic]

Is equivalent to (note the added "1"):

NestGraph[Mod[#^2 + 1, 10] &, Range[0, 9], 1,VertexLabels -> Automatic]

Which can be mapped to:

NestList[Mod[#^2 + 1, 10] &, Range[0, 9], 1] 

Which yields:

{ {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, {1,2,5,0,7,6,7,0,5,2} } 

And if you Transpose[%] that, you get all directed edges:

{ {0,1}, {1,2}, {2,5}, {3,0}, {4,7}, {5,6}, {6,7}, {7,0}, {8,5}, {9,2} }

Still trying to figure out the original question though... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured this out for those who might be interested, which seems remote :-)

While referring to the image of the above graph, we have:

```
Column[NestList[{2 #, 2 # + 1} &, 0, 2]]
0
{0, 1}
{{0, 2}, {1, 3}}
```

There are three rows. Mapping from the first row to the second, we have:

- 0 to 0, producing the 0 -> 0 edge (loop).
- 0 to 1, producing the 0 -> 1 edge.

Mapping from the second row to the third, we have:

- 0 to 0, again.
- 1 to 2, producing the 1 -> 2 edge.
- 0 to 1, again.
- 1 to 3, producing the 1 -> 3 edge.

This row by row mapping can be extended as needed to explain "confusing" NestGraph output (at least for me anyway).